# Laravel trying to select belongsTo relationship columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a Eloquent Model `App\Listing` which `belongsTo` `App\Product`

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

In the Listing Controller, I'm trying to get a specific listing with 2 columns (`name`, `keywords`) from the product table with it.

```
public function readListing(Request $request, $listingId)
{
    $query = Listing::query();
    $item = $query->with(['product' => function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->select(['name', 'keywords']);
    }])->findOrFail($listingId);
    return response()->json($item->toArray(), 200);
}
```

I get this error:

**TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\API\ListingController::App\Http\Controllers\API{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo given, called in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 580**

where line 580 is

```
$item = $query->with(['product' => function (Builder $query) {
```

When I **remove the Type Declaration** from the line like so

```
$item = $query->with(['product' => function ($query) {
```

I get a result, but it does not include the 2 columns (`name`, `keywords`) from the product table.

```
{
    id: 1,
    product_id: 1,
    listing_price: 10,
    actual_price: 5,
    in_stock: 1,
    listing_date: null,
    delisting_date: null,
    created_at: "2021-02-24T12:33:48.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-02-24T13:45:25.000000Z",
    deleted_at: null,
    category: "Fruits",
    category_id: 2,
    description: "Rem laudantium aut",
    image_urls: [
        ".../storage/products/February2021/CF3nzhmc0RXevSWdOJcd.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/oBtXf5kBjkAyrazuFDyu.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/GfpaGxSoGLA2FBqGrcDX.jpg"
    ],
    image_medium_urls: [
        ".../storage/products/February2021/CF3nzhmc0RXevSWdOJcd-medium.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/oBtXf5kBjkAyrazuFDyu-medium.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/GfpaGxSoGLA2FBqGrcDX-medium.jpg"
    ],
    image_small_urls: [
        ".../storage/products/February2021/CF3nzhmc0RXevSWdOJcd-small.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/oBtXf5kBjkAyrazuFDyu-small.jpg",
        ".../storage/products/February2021/GfpaGxSoGLA2FBqGrcDX-small.jpg"
    ],
    thumbnail_url: ".../storage/products/February2021/CF3nzhmc0RXevSWdOJcd-small.jpg",
    product: null
}
```

Why is the type declaration causing an issue and how do I get it to select the two columns from the related table?

Comment: Insteady of doing like `return $query->select(['name','keyword'])` Just do like this
`$query->select('name','keyword');` Without the brackets and return keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `foreign_key` in your case `listing_id`

```
    $query = Listing::with(['product' => function ($query) {
    // add listing_id
        return $query->select(['listing_id', 'name', 'keywords']);
    }])
        ->findOrFail($listingId);
```

this mention in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

> When using this feature, you should always include the **id** column and
> any relevant **foreign key** columns in the list of columns you wish to
> retrieve.

Comment: Although the product table does not have a `listing_id` column, It works when I add its primary key column and another dependent column, like so: 

`return $query->select(['id', 'name', 'keywords', 'category_id']);`